# Ubuntu Precise cron.daily issue

Tags: cron, ubuntu-12.04

I have a very strange problem. I've placed a script into /etc/cron.daily on my Ubuntu 12.04 server, gave it the appropriate permissions (0755), and assumed it would run correctly. I guess that was too much of an assumption.

The script name is as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   801 Sep 16 16:24 ehcleanup.sh
```

When I run `run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily` it actually doesn't show up in the list:

```
/etc/cron.daily/apache2
/etc/cron.daily/apt
/etc/cron.daily/aptitude
/etc/cron.daily/dpkg
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/etc/cron.daily/mlocate
/etc/cron.daily/passwd
/etc/cron.daily/standard
```

Am I on drugs, or is there something else that needs to be done to get this script to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man run-parts`

The filenames must follow some rules. Remove the ".sh" and it will be ok.

Comment: Ugh....small, simple things as always. Thank you!